# Como copiar o conteúdo de pagina Web com Java?

Tags: java

Preciso copiar o conteúdo de uma [página web](http://www.acinh.com.br/socios/consulta-associados?acao=buscar&nomeFantasia=&idRamo=189&idProduto=), que de acordo com o `Dropdown` selecionado exibe o conteúdo, são *n* `dropdowns` minha necessidade seria copiar todo o conteúdo dessa página.

Isso é possível?

Comment: De uma olhada nessa url: https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010011 Ai tem um tutorial de como pegar o 'content' de uma url com JAVA, talvez seja útil

Comment: @MatheusSuffi respondi minha questão, obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui com o seguinte código resolver minha necessidade:

```
URL url = null;
File file = new File("C:\\Backup\\page.html");
BufferedWriter outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
def x = 1;
url = new URL("http://site");

BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = inFile.readLine()) != null) {
    logger.info(inputLine.toString())
    outFile.write(inputLine);
    outFile.newLine();
}
logger.info("RAMO: "+x.toString())
x++

inFile.close();
outFile.flush();
outFile.close();
```

Espero que isso ajude aos próximos.